# Please help me with this simple, elementary pseudocode

Tags: loops, for-loop, selection, if-statement

This should be very easy for you guys, but I still can't get it visualized in my mind. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if (flag)
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE (that visits an array in order)}
else
    for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        {LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE (that visits an array in REVERSE order)}
```

The problem is that this block of code cannot be placed in a function, and I don't want to copy/paste it twice. Is there any way I can do that in this manner:

```
if (flag)
    loop = for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
else
    loop = for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--);

loop
{LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE (that visits an array in the order specified in 'loop')}
```

??

Comment: "this block of code cannot be placed in a function" Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create variables for the start and end of the loop, and create a third variable to determine the 'direction' for the iteration.

Then just let the loop run through your ONE block of code.  Like this...

```
int iStart = 0;
int iEnd = 9;
int iIncrement = +1;

if (reverse)
{
    iStart = 9;
    iEnd = 0;
    iIncrement = -1;
}

for (i = iStart; i != iEnd; i += iIncrement)
{
    //...large block of code here...
}
```

Comment: My pleasure, "user486800". :)

Answer (score 1):

Put that LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE in a function, receiving order as a parameter. Then reuse it in any number of loops you need.

Comment: `The problem is that this block of code cannot be placed in a function`

Comment: If it's C or C++ *anything* can be placed in a function. The only question is how much work is involved in putting it in a function. Another alternative: Put that LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE in a macro.

Comment: That's what I felt like doing at first, but I didn't write that code initially, so I don't want to mess with it unless within the limits they assign me. Not to mention the fact that I don't understand most of it... >_>

Comment: @user486800 +1 for explaining the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big your array is. Maybe it is possible to generate an additional array that holds the required indexes in the required order:

```
indexes = []

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  indexes.add(i)

if (!flag)
  indexes.reverse()

for each (i in indexes)
  {LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE}
```

Comment: I like it. FlipScript's answer seems a little bit easier for me, but this is a nice backup plan if the other one does not work for me. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: True. My first approach was like FlipScript's too. But he beat me by 2 minutes so I changed it to this. As you can see in his solution, it's a bit difficult to get the values for the end conditions right. (I guess both are off by one.) But in the end it's more efficient and intuitive. On the other hand the solution in my post is ready for some really funky loops. You could even shuffle the indexes array and thus iterate in a random order. Maybe I'll just link to this post whenever someone wants to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = flag?0:9; i != flag?10:0; i += flag?1:-1)
{
//LARGE_BLOCK_OF_CODE 
}
```

Well I know...:p thats too many if else.

And yes, FlipScript's solution is better though it might not look neat. :)

Comment: that's the result when flag = true ^^. You must use `!=` not `>=` and replace `9` by `10`

Comment: I like this compact version, but FlipScript's elaborate version explains it better. Thanks.

Comment: I like this, too... but it would probably give me a headache a year or two from now when I have to revisit the code and didn't remember how it worked.  I hate to have to study my own code!